# spark withColumn value generation from all column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to add a column from all existing column values in the same row.
For example,

```
col1 col2 ... coln      col_new
------------------      -------
True False ...False     "col1-..."
False True ...True      "col2-...-coln"
```

That is, when a value is True, then add its column name with "-" separator and keep doing the same until the last column. We don't know how many columns we will have.

How can I achieve this with `withColumn()` in Spark? (Scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *columns* are all `BooleanTypes` then you can write a `udf` function to get the *new column* as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val columnNames = df.columns

def concatColNames = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Boolean]) => array.zip(columnNames).filter(x => x._1 == true).map(_._2).mkString("-"))

df.withColumn("col_new", concatColNames(array(df.columns.map(col): _*))).show(false)
```

If the *columns* are all `StringTypes` then you just need to modify the `udf` function as below

```
def concatColNames = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => array.zip(columnNames).filter(x => x._1 == "True").map(_._2).mkString("-"))
```

You should get what you require

Comment: here's the link for that https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)